# making script# samples work?

Tags: script#

They all fail for me

The photo one does nothing. I see a text box and a browse button

The other two fail immediately with saying that window.addEventListener is an unknown method

I really bought the vision after watching mix11 talk. But not being able to see the source, there being almost no docs and the samples all failing has made me ready to change my mind

Anybody got any suggestion for the samples, or other ways to re-inspire me (I have a LOT of javascript to write)

edit: well I have found that the samples all work in chrome but not IE8!

Comment: The samples were optimized for demo, in other words I didn't conditionally use attachEvent vs. addEventListener (intentionally to keep things simple).

Comment: For a real app, I would use jQuery (supported out of the box), or some other event wrapper library that abstracted this difference between browsers. The demos should work on IE9.

Comment: they fail the same on all modes of ie9

Answer (score 1):

I think samples are out of date, though didn't even try them since i started using Script#, as i'm only interested in generating scripts in a type safe environment with compile time checking and intellisense.

If you are going to write lots of scripts, ScriptSharp would help you a lot. Even though i have many years of experience with javascript and feel comfortable working with it, when you develop a web application (not just a few pages) with several ten thousands of script lines, it becomes a very tedious work to modify/extend classes, options, libraries.

Lets list some pros/cons:

**PROS:**

- Intellisense
- Type safety (harder to pass wrong argument types to functions etc.)
- Compile time syntax checking (e.g. no extra comma errors, headaches in IE)
- Will feel safer to change code, add features (my number 1 feature)
- Can import any existing script plugin, and you don't have to memorize their options once you did.
- Familiar object oriented design (it maps to simple prototype inheritance in JS)
- Generated script almost 1-1 matches original source

**CONS:**

- Don't have a steep learning curve but need to learn basics
- Takes some time to import your existing code
- Might miss some C#3/JS features like object initializer, implicitly typed variables, extension methods etc. This means you will have to write a few more lines than matching JS code.
- May cause some addiction and reverting back to write plain scripts will feel harder.
- Don't have a big community like GWT (though its improving with recently setup Git repository etc)

Comment: the samples claim to be 0.7 and they are vs2010 slns so they cant be that old. YOu talk of several things that I dont see documented,importing for example. I would really like to work with dojo but only jquery suypport is there. Any guidance is very welcome

Comment: as i said didn't check samples, just remember that someone asked this and Nikhil answered as they are not updated. you can import any library, but only jquery is built-in, check source code for it in github, you just define a regular c# library with imported classes/methods and put some attributes on them like Imported, IgnoreNamespace, ScriptName etc.

Comment: The samples are in fact updated. It is the readme doc that hasn't been updated, though a good chunk of it is still valid. However, I agree the readme needs updating. Working on that...

Answer (score 0):

The MIX11 code and slides were published here:

http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp-MIX11.aspx